# Spring batch use JpaPagingItemReader JpaItemWriter no transaction is in progress

Tags: jpa, spring-data, spring-batch

My project uses java config, the `DataSource` entityManagerFactory `PlatformTransactionManager` created by other java config file.

When `ItemReader` read data, `ItemProcessor` data transformed `ItemWriter` has some error

How can I solve this problem?

Error message

```
2015-01-17 16:26:30.390 ERROR AbstractStep:225 - Encountered an error executing step testStep in job validJob
javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.checkTransactionNeeded(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1171)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.flush(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1332)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
```

How can I enable transactions on the following Code:

```
  @Configuration
        @EnableBatchProcessing
        public class JobConfiguration {   

     @Inject
            private PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager;

         @Inject
            private EntityManagerFactory emf;    

         @Bean
            public Job validJob(JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory,Step step) {
                return jobBuilderFactory.get("validJob").flow(step).end().build();
            }

            @Bean
            public Step testStep(StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory, ItemReader<PurchaseOrder> reader,
                    ItemWriter<PurchaseOrder> writer, ItemProcessor<PurchaseOrder, PurchaseOrder> processor) {
                return stepBuilderFactory.get("testStep")//
                        .transactionManager(transactionManager)//
                        .<PurchaseOrder, PurchaseOrder>chunk(100)//
                        .reader(reader)//
                        .processor(processor)//
                        .writer(writer)//
                        .build();
            }

            @Bean
            public ItemReader<PurchaseOrder> reader() {
                JpaPagingItemReader<PurchaseOrder> reader = new JpaPagingItemReader<PurchaseOrder>();
                reader.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);
                reader.setQueryString(" select p from PurchaseOrder p ");
                reader.setTransacted(false);
                return reader;
            }

            @Bean
            public ItemProcessor<PurchaseOrder, PurchaseOrder> processor() {
                return new PurchaseOrderItemProcessor();
            }

            @Bean
                        public ItemWriter<PurchaseOrder> writer() {
                JpaItemWriter<PurchaseOrder> writer = new JpaItemWriter<PurchaseOrder>();
                writer.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);
                return writer;

            }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Your question will be better received if you fix blatant typos and make the sentences read smoothly.  If English is not your first language, at least spell check.

Comment: Sorry, next time I'll be a lot of questions before submitting checks.

Comment: Is the transaction manager configured above the same one that you're using for the job as a whole?  If so, the chunk should be wrapped in a transaction by default...